# Couldn't catch the IndexError and print the statement, also loop back to the input

Tags: python, try-except, index-error

I can loop the ValueError, but only ValueError will print the statement

And the IndexError will stop the code, which I want to keep asking the user for the 'line number'.

```
def file_content(file_name):
    user_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    content = user_file.readlines()
    user_file.close()
    return content

def main():
    file_name = input('Enter the name of the file: ')

    try:
        content = file_content(file_name)
    

    except IOError:
        print ('File can not be fount. Program will exit.')
        exit()

    while True:
    
        try:
            line_number = input('Enter a line number: ')
            line_number = int(line_number)
            break
        
        
        except IndexError:
            print ('That is not a valid line number. Try again.')
        
        except ValueError:
            print ('You need to enter an integer for the line number. Try again.')
        
    
        
    
    print ('The line you requested:')
    print (content[line_number-1])

    
main()
```

**This is what happens when I run the code**

```
Enter the name of the file: datas.txt
Enter a line number: w
You need to enter an integer for the line number. Try again.
Enter a line number: 99
The line you requested:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yenvivian/Desktop/Python HW/hw04.py", line 40, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/yenvivian/Desktop/Python HW/hw04.py", line 37, in main
print (content[line_number-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch an exception, the code that raises the exception must be *inside* of the `try`:

```
try:
    line_number = input('Enter a line number: ')
    line_number = int(line_number)

    print ('The line you requested:')
    print (content[line_number-1])  # Inside the try

    break
        
        
except IndexError:
    print ('That is not a valid line number. Try again.')
    
except ValueError:
    print ('You need to enter an integer for the line number. Try again.')
```